# Excel/VBA: Adding a title to doughnut chart reduces size of doughnut

Tags: excel, vba, charts

...but I want my doughnut to be full sized. As I want to move the title to the center of the doughnut, I don't need the top margin, which is added, it seems, through `Chart.HasTitle = True`. How can I work around this?

Examplary code

```
Sub createChart()
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    Dim chrt As ChartObject
    Dim dataRng As Range

    Dim lft As Integer
        lft = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Left
    Dim wdth As Integer
        wdth = 500
    Dim hgt As Integer
        hgt = 300
    Dim tp As Integer
        tp = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Top
    
    Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=lft, Width:=wdth, Height:=hgt, Top:=tp)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "A" & i
        With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            .Value = i / 55
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
    Next i
    Set dataRng = Range("A1:B10")

    With chrt.Chart
        .ChartType = xlDoughnut
        .SetSourceData Source:=dataRng
        ' comment out from here
        .HasTitle = True
        With .ChartTitle
            .Text = "Test"
            .Top = hgt / 2
            .Left = wdth / 2 - 20
        End With
        ' to here
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are aware that in the line `Dim lft, wdth, hgt, tp As Integer`, only tp is dimensioned as an integer? The rest will be variants unless you specify those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line `.ChartTitle.IncludeInLayout = False` after `.HasTitle = True`.

You can read the [documentation on the property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.charttitle.includeinlayout) for more details on what it does, but basically you set it to

> True if a chart title will occupy the chart layout space when a chart layout is being determined

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a title, you could add an overlaying element like so:

```vb
Sub testCreateChart()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    Dim chrt As ChartObject
    Dim dataRng As Range

    Dim lft, wdth, hgt, tp As Integer
        lft = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Left
        wdth = 500
        hgt = 300
        tp = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Top
    
    Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=lft, Width:=wdth, Height:=hgt, Top:=tp)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "A" & i
        With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            .Value = i / 55
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
    Next i
    Set dataRng = Range("A1:B10")

    With chrt.Chart
        .ChartType = xlDoughnut
        .SetSourceData Source:=dataRng
        ' comment out from here
        .SetElement msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay
        With .ChartTitle
            
            .Text = "Test"
            .Top = hgt / 2 - 20
            .Left = wdth / 2 - 20
        End With
        ' to here
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solutions works wonderfully. I prefer the other solution because I do not understand how `Chart.SetElement(MsoChartElementType)` Method works yet

Comment: Yeah, I hate `SetElement`. It seems like a workaround rather than an actual method.

Comment: @JonPeltier when you record a macro an use the default options available (add element -> title -> overlay), then the recorded macro uses `SetElement`...

Comment: Yes, and I always replace it with the more explicit code.